# Выделитель цифр из строки с запятыми

Tags: 1с, строки

Помогите решить задачу. Дано поле ввода `Строка1` со строкой: "`1,2,3,4,5`". Мне надо записать каждую цифру в отдельное поле ввода. И чтобы код был написан в процедуре. У меня получается записать только первую и последнюю цифру. Вот так:

```
Строка2=Лев(Строка1, Найти(В1,",")-1);
Строка6=Прав(Строка1, Найти(В1,",")-1);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот так короче:

```
Стр = СтрЗаменить(Стр, ",", Символы.ПС);
МассивСтрок = Новый Массив();
Для Счетчик = 1 По СтрЧислоСтрок(Стр) Цикл
  МассивСтрок.Добавить(СокрЛП(СтрПолучитьСтроку(Стр,Счетчик)));
КонецЦикла;
```

Comment: Согласен. Короче и более понимаемо.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно разложить строку в массив подстрок.
Делается это циклом с поиском символа разделителя.

Пример рабочей функции

```
Функция РазложитьСтрокуВМассивПодстрок(Знач Стр, Разделитель = ",") Экспорт

МассивСтрок = Новый Массив();

Если Разделитель = " " Тогда

    Стр = СокрЛП(Стр);
    Пока Истина Цикл //Вечный цикл. выход возможен только по Прервать
        Поз = Найти(Стр,Разделитель); 
        Если Поз=0 Тогда
            МассивСтрок.Добавить(Стр);
            Возврат МассивСтрок;
        КонецЕсли;
        МассивСтрок.Добавить(Лев(Стр,Поз-1));
        Стр = СокрЛ(Сред(Стр,Поз));
    КонецЦикла;

Иначе

    ДлинаРазделителя = СтрДлина(Разделитель);

    Пока Истина Цикл //Вечный цикл. выход возможен только по Прервать

        Поз = Найти(Стр,Разделитель);

        Если Поз=0 Тогда
            МассивСтрок.Добавить(Стр);
            Возврат МассивСтрок;
        КонецЕсли;

        МассивСтрок.Добавить(Лев(Стр,Поз-1));
        Стр = Сред(Стр,Поз+ДлинаРазделителя);

    КонецЦикла;

КонецЕсли;
```

КонецФункции

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример из УПП

```
Функция РазложитьСтрокуВМассивПодстрок(Знач Стр, Разделитель = ",") Экспорт

    МассивСтрок = Новый Массив();
    Если Разделитель = " " Тогда
        Стр = СокрЛП(Стр);
        Пока 1 = 1 Цикл
            Поз = Найти(Стр, Разделитель);
            Если Поз = 0 Тогда
                МассивСтрок.Добавить(Стр);
                Возврат МассивСтрок;
            КонецЕсли;
            МассивСтрок.Добавить(Лев(Стр, Поз - 1));
            Стр = СокрЛ(Сред(Стр, Поз));
        КонецЦикла;
    Иначе
        ДлинаРазделителя = СтрДлина(Разделитель);
        Пока 1 = 1 Цикл
            Поз = Найти(Стр, Разделитель);
            Если Поз = 0 Тогда
                Если (СокрЛП(Стр) <> "") Тогда
                    МассивСтрок.Добавить(Стр);
                КонецЕсли;
                Возврат МассивСтрок;
            КонецЕсли;
            МассивСтрок.Добавить(Лев(Стр,Поз - 1));
            Стр = Сред(Стр, Поз + ДлинаРазделителя);
        КонецЦикла;
    КонецЕсли;

КонецФункции
```

Входные данные: "1,2,3,4,555,67,8346"
Результат:
Индекс  Значение элемента
0   "1"
1   "2"
2   "3"
3   "4"
4   "555"
5   "67"
6   "8346"